# Polyhedral graph such that every vertex has degree $2k$, for some $k > 2$

Tags: graph-theory, polyhedra

Is there any polyhedral graph such that every vertex has degree even greater than 4?

Comment: This is a direct consequence of a well-known fact about planar graphs.  See [this previous Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/252053/planar-graphs-with-n-geq-2-vertices-have-at-least-two-vertices-whose-degree-i) and reply if it does not completely address your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a graph's every vertex has degree of at least $6$, then it cannot be planar graph because it needs to satisfy Euler's formula.

See [this MO question's comment by Noam Elkies](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/124116/maximum-number-of-edges-in-a-planar-graph) for details.

Answer (score 2):

Let $V$, $F$, $E$ be the number of vertices, faces and edges.  If every vertex has degree $\ge 6$, $E \ge 3 V$.  Every face has at least three edges, so 
$E \ge 3 F/2$.  Thus the Euler characteristic $V-E+F < E/3 - E + 2 E/3 = 0$.
This can't occur for a spherical polyhedron or a handle-body, though I suppose it could for some exotic non-orientable "polyhedron".